# How to get custom values in magento cart page?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

In my store, I need some value passing to the Product listing page. And the passing values need to be get it in Cart page. My sample code is here,

I add some custom values like this,

```
$description = "Pendant Shape: ".$pen_shape." "."Pendant Color: ".$pen_color." "."Necklace Color: ".
```

Add I pass the values like this,

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params, $description);
```

How can I get it this **$description** value in cart page. Any Suggestion or help must be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you know there is a Magento SE site? Currently in beta: http://magento.stackexchange.com/